# C# List of Items with multiple values

Tags: c#, list, tuples

Firstly please forgive me as I am still trying to get to grips with C# and OOP.

I am trying to build a simple console shopping basket as part of a challenge and I have a number of products which I need to be able to pull on to populate 5 different scenarios of the basket.

However I am unsure as to the best approach to listing each of the products which each have three different values (Desc, Dept, Price) and I wish to be able to select the items I need through a array, possibly.

Currently I have the items listed as such:

```
        itemOnePrice = 10.50m;
        itemTwoPrice = 54.65m;
        itemThreePrice = 03.50m;
        itemOneDept = "Clothing";
        itemTwoDept = "Clothing";
        itemThreeDept = "Head Gear";
        itemOneDesc = "Hat";
        itemTwoDesc = "Jumper";
        itemThreeDesc = "Head Light";
```

I have looked at Lists and at Tuple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to really make these work for me. Can somebody please explain the best approach to list these products to pull from to populate my basket contents.

Comment: You should have an `item` class that has `price`, `description`, and `department` and then have an array of `item`.

Comment: Please define what is your criteria for "better" so "the best approach" can be provided. Note that it seem like you have yet to read about arrays/classes in C# - you may want to finish those chapters of a book first before asking questions on SO.

Comment: By better I mean anything which means that I'm not creating a huge amount of variables as I know this isn't the best way to approach what I am trying to achieve.

I spent ages trying to get Tuple to work but I found that I was unable to successfully initialize it and a list initially seemed to only allow me one value, though I can see from responses that it isn't the case.

I've spent hours trying to get it working and researching various methods, but there is a limit to what I currently understand.

I didn't realise I would be down voted for asking a basic question, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a class

```
class Item
{
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public string Department {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Second, create the list

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

items.Add(new Item{Price = 10.5m, Department = "Clothing", Description = "Hat"});
items.Add(new Item{Price = 54.65m, Department = "Clothing", Description = "Jumper"});
items.Add(new Item{Price = 03.50m, Department = "Head Gear", Description = "Head Light"});
```

Comment: No way this is "the best" approach. What is the reason to create mutable properties? I'd argue that immutable class would be better that one you proposed. Make sure to discuss that. Also `Desc` is not a word - how that could be better than "Description"?

Comment: Fix Price setter.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It depends the OP's requirements. Without looking at the details, I can't say anything.